# Webpage Forwarding

Tags: c#, jquery, html, request, forward

I am creating a little project which has the aim of bypassing location based websites. I am not fussed about encryption etc...

So far, I have created a site which does this:

http://www.mysite.com?q=http://www.myothersite.com

and it returns the HTML for that website. Pretty standard, easy stuff.

My problem is I am not sure how I would capture the requests fired from that page. I could simply do a textbased replace in the HTML to change all requests to filter through my page, but that wouldn't help with any AJAX based requests.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you very much for your help,

Richard Hughes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer, I didn't do any of the above. I purchased a VPN package.